# Межпроцессное взаимодействие между .Net Core хостом и .Net Framework клиентом

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, ipc

Скажите пожалуйста, какими способами можно организовать межпроцессное взаимодействие между .Net Core  и .Net Framework приложениями?

Comment: Grpc, сокеты, именованные каналы, memory mapped files

Comment: или если клиент далеко то http запросы как api

Comment: А разве gRPC клиент может быть .net Framework? Читал много материала, везде пишут что только .net Core

Comment: @Vlad `А разве gRPC клиент может быть .net Framework?` На core microsoft сделал сейчас свою обертку для asp. Обертка использует эту [либу](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grpc/)